# 2000 Dodge Neon flooding problem

Tags: dodge, neon, water-leak

This is a very common problem with Dodge Neon cars. They flood in the back seats big time. I had this problem with 1998 Dode Neon (manual), then bough 2000 Neon. Inititially it did not flood at all but now it does. I searched the forms, could not find a  solution anywhere. Does anyone know why Neons flood with water in rain?

Comment: Is it Convertible? Sun-Roof? The more specific you are, the better the answer.

Comment: I have never seen a convertable dogde neon. No it is not. To clarify more, everything else in the car is dry, windows, mirrors, seats, consoles, dashboard, everythingg but there is pile of water in the rear back. I believe it is more of those recall problems but they never addressed it.

Comment: Do you have any sort of roof antenna? Or if not centralized, can the windows be leaking?

Comment: NOT AT ALL. Everything else is dry just the floors and there is pool of water in car! Obviosly if there is so much water (not just wet), this must be a design fault when everything else is dry.

Comment: Yeah, that's just weird. Have you called anyone to see if maybe there is a recall for this? Sometimes they put bulletins out, they are not actual recalls, but they work the same.

Comment: I think I will better write an article on it to bring their attention. Will verify if they was ever a recall on it.

Comment: I have the same problem with my 2000 Chrysler Neon. Has been leaking since 2004 or 2005. Puddles on the floor in the back seat, no sunroof, no damage to the door seals or trunk seals. Seats are dry, interior roof liner is dry, door panels are dry. The trunk liner gets wet as well. The only possible culprit I have been able to see is the weather strip on the bottom of the rear window, but I can't see water running "in" anywhere. There is rust on the floor now, but this isn't the location of the leak either (car fills up when parked). Is there any information anywhere from Dodge/Chrysler on this

Answer (score 1):

I wish you luck.  In my experience any car that's 10 years old or more is probably leaking somewhere, just most times people haven't noticed yet (although, they eventually notice when the floor rusts through and falls out).  The causes of leaks are multitude.  You just have to go around every spot where there's a break in the metal (antennas, windows, trim, handles, gas doors, etc.) and inspect carefully/hose down while watching for water...

Comment: This problem is abudant with Neons. My 2000 is in very good condition and clean. The only way I can see what is underneath is take all the carpet out but I dont' suspect anything wrong there. To me it does look like a design flaw that shows up when the car gets older. The most prominent suspect is underneath the mat but then I wonder how. No one even sits in the back that it would get damaged.

Comment: I really doubt anything from underneath is soaking your rear seats and/or floor in such a way that you would notice unless you are fording rivers in a neon. Prime suspects in this order. rear window seal, trunk seal, rear door seals.

Answer (score 1):

The flooding problem is probably the funky gaskets used around the tail lights.  Get some silicone, take the tail light assembly off and on the left side run a bead of silicone.  The water runs down the trunk track right along the left side of the gasket and ruins it's properties over time.  The gaskets cost around $12.00 on ebay but from what I've read online in other forums, the lifespan isn't much over 5 years before they start leaking again.

You'll want to check the spare tire well also.  Mine had 4 inches of water in it prior to sealing the leaky spot with silicone.

There is also another leak very common on Dodge Neons, and that is in the front under the dash.  If the AC condensation overflow hose gets plugged it will send all that water down the inside of the firewall, along whatever wires it comes into contact with, shorting out your CD player and radio and filling the passenger side floorboards with water.  To fix that, take an airhose, stuff it into the drain hose and shoot a few short bursts of air into it.  If it is plugged you will have Niagara flowing within seconds.

Hope this helps someone.